# Should the synchronous operation that build the query to DB be wrapped into Task.FromResult()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, ienumerable, iqueryable

I have a code and I'm feeling (but not quite sure) there is a code smell in it:

This method calls repository method `GetAllByOrderIdAsync`:

```
List<IncomingBatch> incomingBatches = 
            (await _incomingBatchRepository.GetAllByOrderIdAsync(orderId)).ToList();
```

The repository class:

```
internal class IncomingBatchRepository : EfBaseEntityRepository<IncomingBatch>, IIncomingBatchRepository
{
    public IncomingBatchRepository(WarehouseMSSQLContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    // actually my concerns about this method
    public async Task<IEnumerable<IncomingBatch>> GetAllByOrderIdAsync(Guid incomingOrderId)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(Entities.Join(_context.IncomingOrderGoods
                .Where(goods => goods.IncomingOrderId == incomingOrderId),
            batch => batch.Id,
            goods => goods.IncomingBatchId,
            (batch, goods) => batch));
    }
}
```

The `Entities` comes from the base repository class that have a `DbSet<T>` type:

```
public abstract class EfBaseEntityRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    // ctor omitted for brevity

    protected virtual DbSet<T> Entities => _context.Set<T>();

    // another methods omitted for brevity
}
```

So what I don't like in this code is that `GetAllByOrderIdAsync` is not a trully asynchronous method. As far as I understand it's syncronously build a query.

I'm thinking to refactor this code as follows:

```
List<IncomingBatch> incomingBatches =
            await _incomingBatchRepository.GetAllByOrderIdAsync(orderId);
```

and to change the return type to `List<IncomingBatch>` and execute the query here:

```
internal class IncomingBatchRepository : EfBaseEntityRepository<IncomingBatch>, IIncomingBatchRepository
{
    public IncomingBatchRepository(WarehouseMSSQLContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public async Task<List<IncomingBatch>> GetAllByOrderIdAsync(Guid incomingOrderId)
    {
        return await
            Entities.Join(_context.IncomingOrderGoods
                .Where(goods => goods.IncomingOrderId == incomingOrderId),
            batch => batch.Id,
            goods => goods.IncomingBatchId,
            (batch, goods) => batch)
             .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

What do you think about all of this? Is there any code smell in the original code? Should I refactor it or there is no reason to concern?

Comment: All this code is unnecessary. A DbContext is already a Unit-Of-Work, a DbSet is already a repository. And `GetAllByOrderIdAsync` isn't async, all the operations it performs are synchronous. It enumerates the `IQueryable` produced by `Where` *synchronously*. You'd need eg `ToListAsync()` or `AsAsyncEnumerable` to execute the query asynchronously

Comment: Read Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) and Oren Eini's [Repository is the new Signleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton). By putting a low-level abstraction like a "generic" repository over a high level abstraction like an ORM, you gain nothing in terms of abstraction but introduce correctness and performance problems.